# Can a planet have a one-way mirror atmospheric layer?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere

I would like a planet with Earth-breathable atmosphere, but I would like some substance at the top layer that acts like a one-way mirror: from the ground, people can look up and see the stars, moon, sun, etc, but a ship in orbit would see only an opaque sphere when on the sun-lit side. Is there any chemistry that would create such an effect?

Comment: It would be difficult, as first the Universe would have to invent a true one-way mirror. Which is, really, just an optical illusion caused by inadequate Human eyes. What you call one-way mirror the reality calls "being fooled by a reflection brighter than the transmission through it from a dimly-lit space"

Answer (score 11):

### No, you misunderstand the physics of a one-way mirror.

A one way mirror is simply a "mirror surfaced" that is only partially mirrored. I.e, a significant portion of light is not reflected by the mirror, but transmits through the mirror.

Consider the standard police interview room with a one-way mirror.

The interview room is brightly-lit, and the side room is relatively dark.

Because the interview room is brightly lit, the amount of light in the reflection is much more that the amount of light transmitted from the dark side room through the mirrored glass. The means that the image of the dark room coming through the glass is swamped by the bright light in the reflection.

From the dark room side of the mirror, the situation is reversed - the amount of reflected light from the dark room is small, and the amount of light coming from the interview room is bright, allowed the hidden observers to see clearly into the interview room.

For a one-way sky-view at night side which has dim lights in the sky, you are one the wrong side of the mirrored surface (depending on the relative amounts of light). While the sun, and perhaps the moon and bright stars would be sufficiently bright to be visible from the ground-side, dimmer sources would be washed out if the ground side is well lit (as would be true in a modern city).

In the countryside with minimal ground lighting, even dimmer stars would be visible because ground-lighting is low.

From space-side viewing the ground. the issue is reverse. Bright ground sources would be visible, but dark ground sources would not.

Having a partially reflecting layer in the atmosphere is not hard to imagine, and it occurs naturally under some conditions. It is commonly observed with desert mirages.

---

A mirage is an example of atmospheric reflection that defends upon 2 things. One is usually an inversion layer, the other being a low-angle of incidence in the reflected light - which is more easily reflected than light that is nearly perpendicular to the reflecting layer.

Creating a reflecting layer through chemistry is not easy, a reflecting surface needs to have a relatively sharply defined layer with differing optical properties - such as seen in a temperature inversion layer. Trying to create a layer through chemistry is not something I can see any way to do. There are 2 approaches:

1. create a layer of gas with a difference refractive index. Problem is that the atmosphere mixes quite well, and you will not manage to have a clean layer that will reflect
2. Introduce a reflective liquid or solid. Same issue, atmosphere mixing will tend to mix the layers, leaving no defined layer to be an effective mirror.

Say you manage to seed the atmosphere with a reflecting particle or alternate gas, there is no layer in the atmosphere that will be stable for a long duration, destroying your reflective layer in short order. It sounds to me like you were asking for a more-or-less permanent layer in your question, which will not be possible.

Comment: The dayside setup you describe is exactly what I asked for in the question (or thought I asked for). How can it be achieved?

Comment: @SRM "How can it be achieved?"  Gaseous unobtanium.

Answer (score 7):

#### Just a thin layer of dust up very high.

As has already been pointed out you wont get a perfect one way mirror. But if you goal is:

- people on surface can see stars and sun, and other light sources.
- people in orbit can't see anything but a uniform sphere.

Surround you planet in a thin layer of dust. Say theres a volcano erupting continuously somewhere and the ash is getting constantly fed into the high atmosphere.

Bright lights from space can penetrate it, sun and moon are bright, and while the night sky may be less vibrant, many bright stars will be visible at night (astronomy will be harder but if born there they wont know any better). Enough for navigation in the age of sail, romantic night time scenes at lookouts in the age of cars, and the odd shooting star to wish on.

But if you look from space you only see the dust layer, as nothing on the surface is bright enough to get through. An extremely big city lights might just be a faint change in brightness tops.

The dust is basically invisible from the ground because it's so high up. Most visible side effect from the planet side is fantastic sunsets - assuming similar atmospheric conditions to earth the dust layer creates very vibrant red effects at low angles light.